# Dell with Intel SandyBridge and HD Radeon 6470M

Tags: intel-graphics, dell, radeon, ati, inspiron

I got a new Dell Inspiron 15R and I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10.

The problem is that when I'm using my computer, after 20 minutes or something, my screen starts to flash and flick a lot.

It's a lot annoying and even more when u are trying to programming some code! :)

It gets worse when u use the trackpad, really have no idea why, but it gets a lot worse. So I have to use an usb mouse but it doesnt solve the problem at all.

Please anyone could help me out with that?

I've searched a lot and I really dont know anymore what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse:

In ubuntu the option `Disable touchpad while typing` is default on. Go to System Settings -> mouse and touchpad to turn it off.

As for your graphics problem, I am trying to figure that out. I'm using my intel HD graphics 3000 (gpu in core i5 cpu), and trying to use the hd radeon instead. Please hang on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Hannes. I will keep waiting u for some good news.